# Recognizing few integers in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, substring

I am receiving a string from server in this format:

> 0_1_2_3

My task is to select for digits from this string to fill four labels with them.
First idea was:

```
NSString *res1 = [result substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
[firstLabel setText:res1];
```

four times with appropriate labels.
But operation will repeats many times and every time I will receive a string with increased digit values. So when every digit be a decimal this code will not work. So how can I track every digit independently from their length in a proper way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSString` comes with a convenience method called [`-componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_)

```
NSString *myString = @"0_1_2_3";
NSArray *myDigitStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];

/* access digit strings from myDigitStrings array by index or fast enumeration... */
for (NSString *myDigitString in myDigitStrings)
    NSLog(@"digit string: %@", myDigitString);
```

Comment: Absolutely fastest way! Thanks, Alex

Comment: If you get a `char *` back from the server, then an even faster way would be to tokenize on the delimiter, but if you're using Foundation objects then it is often best to use the methods Apple provides, which are often optimized for use with other Foundation objects.

Comment: I'll also prefer char * array of characters and scan one by one character to check there ASCII value within the range of ASCII values for numerics.